# How to get the location of some points in processing

Tags: processing

So I'm using the Hype library to draw a polygon with a randomized number of edges.

I would like to draw a point at each intersection of these arrays. 
The problem being that I don't have the coordinates of these edges, I created an object type HPath inherent to this library in which I specified what size I wanted the polygon to be, its global location and the number of edges.

Is there a method to get the coordinates of whatever is drawn on screen ?

Here is the code if that can help :

```
import hype.*;

 HPath poly1;

 void setup() {
  size(640,640);
  H.init(this).background(#CCCCCC);

   poly1 = new HPath();
  poly1
    .polygon( (int)random(6,12) ) // numEdges
    .size(400,400)
    .strokeWeight(2)
    .stroke(#FFFFFF, 200)
    .noFill()
    .anchorAt(H.CENTER)
    .loc(width/2, height/2)
  ;


}

void draw() {

  H.add(poly1);
  H.drawStage();





}
```

Thanks !

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your question. What do you mean by "arrays"? What is H? Is it from the hype library? Can you maybe show the output of that sketch and draw (in Paint or whatever) what you want to achieve? I suppose the poly1 object will still have a reference to its geometry which you can use to calculate intersects.

Answer (score 0):

`HPath` has [`numVertices()`](https://github.com/hype/HYPE_Processing/blob/master/src/main/java/hype/HPath.java#L57) and [`vertex(index)`](https://github.com/hype/HYPE_Processing/blob/master/src/main/java/hype/HPath.java#L61) which should allow you to loop through all the vertices in all HPaths.

Each vertex is in `HVertex` intance which has a [intersectTest()](https://github.com/hype/HYPE_Processing/blob/master/src/main/java/hype/HVertex.java#L303) method you could use.

These ingredients you should suffice.

If you're interested in geometry in Processing you should also check out the [Geomerative library](http://www.ricardmarxer.com/geomerative/). If you want resources on learning / coding these sort of intersections yourself check out [Paul Bourke's website](http://paulbourke.net/geometry/pointlineplane/)